# DOMDocument cannot parse XML: DOMDocument::loadXML()

Tags: zend-framework, domdocument, gdata

When I am executing the code below:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Gapps');
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient("amdminuser", "adminpsw", Zend_Gdata_Gapps::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);
$client->createUser($username, $givenName, $familyName, $password, $passwordHashFunction=null, $quota=null)
```

it gives error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Gdata_HttpClient::createUser() in ....
```

Then we run the installation checker but it showed us this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_Exception' with message 'DOMDocument cannot parse XML: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Extra content at the end of the document in Entity, line: 1' in /web/web2/apache2/htdocs/test/per_ak/google/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php:830 Stack trace: #0 /web/web2/apache2/htdocs/test/per_ak/google/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(789): Zend_Gdata_App::importString('importUrl('https://gdata.y...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...', NULL) #2 /web/web2/apache2/htdocs/test/per_ak/google/library/Zend/Gdata.php(162):
```

I have downloaded http://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendGdata-1.12.0/ZendGdata-1.12.0.zip, installed and set appropriate include_path in php.ini. However, I don't know  why I am getting this problem and errors. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createUser` is a method of Zend_Gdata_Gapps class. Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient returns an Zend_Gdata_HttpClient object.

Are you sure you've read the manual?

Comment: Thank for quickly reply. I used documant of google. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#creating_a_user_account

Comment: When I run installation checker, why did I show this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_Exception' with message 'DOMDocument cannot parse XML: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Extra content at the end of the document in Entity, line: 1' in /web/web2/apache2/htdocs/test/per_ak/google/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php:830 Stack trace: #0 /web/web2/apache2/htdocs/test/per_ak/google/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(789): Zend_Gdata_App::importString('importUrl('https://gdata.y...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...', NULL) #2 /web/web2/apache2/htdocs/test/per_ak/google/library/Zend/Gdata.php(162):